# How are project interdependencies managed in MS Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++

Probably a pretty fundamental question. When developing a single-project-solution in MSVC++ everything makes a lot of sense, every file is visible to the compiler. When moving to a multiple project solution, none of the interface elements governing project dependence seem to make sense (coming from a .net background.)

For starters it appears setting up project dependencies with that terminology seems to only imply what order the projects are compiled in. There is no more function attached to the definition and addressing objects or methods of one project from another will not work. #including the headers of the dependency doesn't seem to work either, so the dependent project cannot see the files of its dependency. Copying a link of a header from one project to another doesn't work either, where for two projects under the 'Header Files' section, the same file is referenced in both locations. Even with this header references do not work and the files are unconnected. The only way of creating a functional dependency is to add the dependency's paths to the linker/compiler search path of the dependent or worse, simply copying the files of one project to another.

Either I'm missing something or the .NET Visual Studio IDEs have succeeded at what the VC++ IDE has badly failed at.

**Edit:**

For the sake of asking a specific question, take the following steps for creating a solution in VC++ and I ask if the missing step(s) can be filled in:

1. Create empty DLL project inside new solution.
2. Create method in DLL project and compile.
3. Create new empty executable project.
4. Create main method in new project.
5. ...
6. Have main method call function in DLL project.

Preferably fill in the missing step(s) with the most most modern/industry standard/best practice method that best maintains project modularity as intended.

From this I would expect to independently be able to extrapolate and create classes, enumerations etc. in the DLL class and access them all in the executable project, so long as I can find out how this is intended to be done.

Comment: You'll have to de-tune your expectations, the C++ build model dates from the 1970s and was certainly not designed to accommodate an IDE.  Ask a *specific* question.

Comment: I could ask hundreds of questions, one answer might make most of them redundant and I don't know enough to ask a specific question. I accept you might have to make some assumptions about my skill level to give an answer but that might be required. Surely the IDE, even over something archaic is at best trying to capture best practices, minimise tedious management aspects and repitition, without limiting freedom. What I don't know is what the IDE is trying to do to help me and what is left for me to do for myself to make even the simplest collection of projects work together.

Comment: Which Visual Studio version? Microsoft broke the project dependency UI in VS2010. I don't know if it's already fixed in VS2013, but in VS2012 it's still broken. The actual mechanism works, barely.

Comment: Actually it's 2008 Express, which itself could be another awesome source of confusion.

Comment: Little reason to stick with an ancient version of a free IDE.  It was in fact improved, you can use the Add Reference context menu item to add a project reference to a LIB or DLL project.  It automatically adds the .lib as a link dependency and sets the build order.  In VS2008 you have to do this yourself with the Project Dependencies context menu item and the linker's Additional Dependencies setting.

Comment: @Hans Passant it's true it's best to be up-to-date, just have the weight of a whole organisation to bring forward. Thanks for your help also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 2, as per the usual C++ rules, declare the method in the header. Read up on  `__declspec(DllExport)` since the default is that methods are internal to the DLL.

In step 5, as per the usual C++ rules, include the header. Visual C++ needs to know where the header is coming from, so you need to reference the source project. Details vary between Visual Studio versions.

In step 6, you call the method in the normal way. Since it's now declared as `__declspec(DllImport)`, the compiler will leave it to the linker, and the linker will get it from the correct DLL.

Comment: Cheers @MSalters, that's kind of what I'm getting at. However I'm slightly confused as to why creating a reference doesn't implicitly add the paths to the header files of the reference if that is going to be required anyway. I still can't compile because somehow it also can't access the *.lib file but it's a start and the dllexport information was definitely useful.

Comment: @JCollins: How would the compiler know where the other project stores its headers? That's not standardized. In particular, it's quite common for DLL projects to have internal and external headers, where the external headers van be given to customers alongside the compiled binary.

Comment: surely at least in this case where both projects are under the umbrella of the same solution, it must know *everything* about how the other project works. In more general cases do the other projects not have to nominate this somehow anyway and likely make the information available? That's the difference between a raw DLL reference and a project reference. Thanks though this is useful stuff, I figured I was missing something in the IDE while doing all these path linking steps manually, didn't feel right.